# Contact form: Horizontal alignment of checkboxes and labels

Tags: checkbox, alignment

I just wondered if someone knew the answer to this. If you do, you are a real web expert!

I am creating a contact form for a musicians website. I have a section where I would like users to select the instrument that they want to learn via a checkbox: e.g.

x piano
x flute
x singing
x violin

etc.

where x is the checkbox.

However I would like the checkboxes and their labels to be aligned horizontally across the page e.g.:

x piano    x flute    x singing    x violin

in order to shorten the length of the form field. Does anyone know how to do this, without separating the labels from the tags and have the labels move to another part of the page?

I would like my form to end up looking more like this form: http://www.bpcollins.co.uk/contact/form 
(esp. the 'services interested in' section).

My code is as follows:

HTML:

I am interested in learning (please tick all that apply):

```
<div class="check">
<label id="checkbox">Piano</label><input id="piano" type="checkbox"              name="instrument" value="Piano">
<label id="checkbox">Flute</label><input id="flute" type="checkbox" name="instrument" value="Flute">
<label id="checkbox">Singing</label><input id="singing" type="checkbox" name="instrument" value="Singing">
<label id="checkbox">Violin</label><input id="violin" type="checkbox" name="instrument" value="Violin">
<label id="checkbox">Keyboard</label><input id="keyboard" type="checkbox" name="instrument" value="Keyboard">
<label id="checkbox">Interview Technique for School and University</label><input id="interview_technique" type="checkbox" name="instrument" value="Interview">
<label id="checkbox">English</label><input id="english" type="checkbox" name="instrument" value="English">
<label id="checkbox">Theatre Training</label><input id="theatre" type="checkbox" name="instrument" value="Theatre">
<label id="checkbox">Speech Development</label><input id="speech" type="checkbox" name="instrument" value="Speech Development">
</div>

<br>
<hr>

<p> I want to enrole as a </p>



<label id="checkbox">Primary School Child</label><input id="primary" type="checkbox" name="child" value="Primary">      
<label id="checkbox">Secondary School Child</label><input id="secondary" type="checkbox" name="child" value="Secondary">
<label id="checkbox">Adult</label><input id="adult" type="checkbox" name="child" value="adult">





<br>
```

CSS:

```
input[type="checkbox"] {
    background-color: #fff;
    font-style: normal;
    background-position: 0px !important;
    padding: 0px;
    border-radius: 0px;
    margin: 10px;
    clear: left;



}

label#checkbox {

    float: left;
    text-align: left;
    position: relative;
    left: 40px;
    top: 18px;

}
```

I would be very grateful for any response!

Regards,

Robert

London
United Kingdom

Answer (score 3):

you could try something like this...

put a

```
<div class="whatever"><label id="checkbox">Flute</label><input id="flute" type="checkbox" name="instrument" value="Flute"></div>
```

around each one

and then in css put

```
.whatever { display: inline-block; }
```

if that doesn't work try .whatever { foat: left; } with or without display: inline-block

make sure your .check container class is wide enough to allow the full checkbox labels and inputs to show

Answer (score -1):

Thank you lawnlanders. I actually found a much better technique was to align the checkboxes and their labels in a table, and then add padding and margin to add some room between the cells.

For example:

```
        <table>
        <tr>
            <td><label id="checkbox">Piano</label><input id="piano" type="checkbox" name="instrument" value="Piano" class="required" title="Please check at least one option.">
            </td>

            <td>
            <label id="checkbox">Flute</label><input id="flute" type="checkbox" name="instrument" value="Flute">
            </td>

            <td>
            <label id="checkbox">Singing</label><input id="singing" type="checkbox" name="instrument" value="Singing">
            </td>
        </tr>


        <tr>
            <td>
            <label id="checkbox">Violin</label><input id="violin" type="checkbox" name="instrument" value="Violin">
            </td>


            <td>
                <label id="checkbox">Keyboard</label><input id="keyboard" type="checkbox" name="instrument" value="Keyboard">
            </td>


            <td>
                <label id="checkbox">Interview Technique</label><input id="interview_technique" type="checkbox" name="instrument" value="Interview">
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>


            <td>
                <label id="checkbox">English</label><input id="english" type="checkbox" name="instrument" value="English">
            </td>


            <td>
                <label id="checkbox">Theatre Training</label><input id="theatre" type="checkbox" name="instrument" value="Theatre">
            </td>


            <td>
                <label id="checkbox">Speech Development</label><input id="speech" type="checkbox" name="instrument" value="Speech Development">
            </td>

        </tr>
    </table>
```

Your technique works, but does not provide the alignment and presentation that comes with the above method.

Thanks!

Comment: Tables are made for listings not for forms or layout.

Answer (score -2):

I used Bob suggestion but like this

```
.whatever { display: inline-block; } 
.whatever input, .whatever label{ float:left !important; }
```

Hope it helps